# Get the downloadURL for each file from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get the downloadURL for each file from the firebase storage. Currently I'm displaying the metadata (in this case the name of each file).

```
  const [fileNames, setFileNames] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getFiles = async () => {
      const storage = await firebase.storage().ref("/recursos");
      const list = await storage.listAll();
      const items = list.items.map((ref) => ref.getMetadata());
      const results = await Promise.all(items);
      setFileNames(results);
    };
    getFiles();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <SinapseNav />
      <Container className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mt-4 mb-4">
        <Card className="home-card">
          <Card.Body>
            <h3 className="text-center mb-4">Pesquisar Recursos</h3>
            <Form.Control placeholder='Ex: "Trigonometria"' />

            {fileNames.map((file) => {
              return (
                <Container key={file.name}>
                  <ResourceCard title={file.name} />
                </Container>
              );
            })}
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What's keeping you from implementing the additional use-case based on the code you have and https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url?

Comment: I have no idea how to get for each of one. I tried to see the docs but it doesn't work... I'm sorry, I'm new to js and react :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.ListResult#items), you can call `getDownloadUrl()` on the items of the [`ListResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.ListResult) you got through [`listAll()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#listall). Exactly the same way than you do with `getMetadata()`.

So the following should do the trick:

```
const getUrls = async () => {
  const storage = firebase.storage().ref("/recursos");
  const list = await storage.listAll();
  const items = list.items.map((ref) => ref.getDownloadUrl());
  const urls = await Promise.all(items);
  // Do whatever you want with the urls Array
};
```

---

Note that `listAll()` has a default pagination size is 1000: It is actually a "helper method for calling `list()` repeatedly until there are no more results".